# How to use webpack to ignore or replace some modules which are not really used?

Tags: webpack

I need to use a package in browser, but it imported some node modules like `fs`. When I use webpack to bundle it, it reports some errors say that `fs` can be only run on node. But the functions used `fs` are not really invoked in my case.

Is there any way to configure webpack to ignore or replace the `fs` dependency? I configured `webpack.config.js` with:

```
resolve: {
  externals: ['fs']
}
```

Although the code can be bundled, but when it's running on browser, it fails since it still want to require `fs`.

I'm wondering if I can create a dummy `fs` replacement for webpack, which is as simple as a empty object `{}`, but I can't find a way to do it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [resolve.alias config option](http://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolve-alias) to replace modules

In your case

```
resolve: {
  alias: {
    fs: './fs-mock.js'
  }
}
```